# How to import immer from redux dev toolkit?

Tags: redux, react-redux, immer.js

Since Immer is already imported from Redux dev toolkit. How do I import Immer from Redux dev toolkit? So that we don't need to add a separate import for immer in package.

Comment: Does `import immer from 'immer';` not work?

Comment: import immer from 'immer' does work, but i want to import immer from redux dev toolkit.

Comment: I see, sorry. I think you're looking for [this](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/other-exports#exports-from-other-libraries) `produce` is `createNextState` [Here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/master/src/index.ts#L3) are all the redux toolkit immer exports

Answer (score 2):

createNextState from redux dev toolkit can be used as produce. You do not want to import immer library as it becomes unnecessary.